# Naive Bayes classifier and discriminant analysis accuracy is way off

Tags: matlab, statistics, cluster-analysis, bayesian, naivebayes

So I have two methods of classification, Discriminant analysis `diaglinear` classification (naive Bayes) and the pure Naive Bayes classifier implemented in matlab, there are 23 classes in the entire dataset. The first method discriminant analysis:

```matlab
%% Classify Clusters using Naive Bayes Classifier and classify
training_data = Testdata; 
target_class = TestDataLabels;

[class, err]  = classify(UnseenTestdata, training_data, target_class,'diaglinear')

cmat1 = confusionmat(UnseenTestDataLabels, class);
acc1 = 100*sum(diag(cmat1))./sum(cmat1(:));
fprintf('Classifier1:\naccuracy = %.2f%%\n', acc1);
fprintf('Confusion Matrix:\n'), disp(cmat1)
```

Yields an accuracy from the confusion matrix of **81.49%** with an error rate (`err`) of **0.5040** (not sure how to interpret that).

The second method Naive Bayes classifier:

```matlab
%% Classify Clusters using Naive Bayes Classifier
training_data = Testdata; 
target_class = TestDataLabels;
%# train model
nb = NaiveBayes.fit(training_data, target_class, 'Distribution', 'mn');

%# prediction
class1 = nb.predict(UnseenTestdata); 

%# performance
cmat1 = confusionmat(UnseenTestDataLabels, class1);
acc1 = 100*sum(diag(cmat1))./sum(cmat1(:));
fprintf('Classifier1:\naccuracy = %.2f%%\n', acc1);
fprintf('Confusion Matrix:\n'), disp(cmat1)
```

Yields an accuracy of **81.89%**.

I have only done one round of cross validation, I'm new at matlab and supervised/unsupervised algorithms so I did the cross validation myself. I just basically take 10% of the data and keep it aside for testing purposes, as it is a random set each time. I could go through it several times and take the average accuracy but the results will do for explanation purposes.

**So to my problem question.**

In my literature review of current methods a lot of researchers are finding that a single classification algorithm mixed with a clustering algorithm are yielding better accuracy results. They do this by finding the optimal number of clusters for their data and using the partitioned clusters (which should be more alike than not) run each individual cluster through a classification algorithm. A process where you can use the best parts of an unsupervised algorithm in conjunction with a supervised classification algorithm.

Now I'm using a dataset that has been used numerous times in literature and I'm attempting a not so dissimilar approach to others in my quest.

I first use the simple K-Means clustering which surprisingly has a good capability to cluster my data. The output looks like so:

[image]

Looking at each cluster (K1, K2...K12) class labels:

```matlab
%% output the class labels of each cluster
K1 = UnseenTestDataLabels(indX(clustIDX==1),:)
```

I find that predominately each cluster has one class label in 9 clusters while 3 clusters contain multiple class labels. Showing that K-means has a good fit to the data.

The **problem** however is once I have each cluster data (cluster1,cluster2...cluster12):

```matlab
%% output the real data of each cluster
cluster1 = UnseenTestdata(clustIDX==1,:)
```

And I put each cluster through the naive Bayes or discriminant analysis like so:

```matlab
class1  = classify(cluster1, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear');
class2  = classify(cluster2, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear');
class3  = classify(cluster3, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear');
class4  = classify(cluster4, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear');
class5  = classify(cluster5, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear');
class6  = classify(cluster6, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear');
class7  = classify(cluster7, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear');
class8  = classify(cluster8, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear');
class9  = classify(cluster9, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear');
class10  = classify(cluster10, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear'); 
class11  = classify(cluster11, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear');
class12  = classify(cluster12, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear');
```

The accuracy becomes horrifying, 50% of the clusters are classified with 0% accuracy, each classified cluster (acc1, acc2,...acc12) has its own corresponding confusion matrix you can see the accuracy of each cluster here:

[image]

So my problem/question is: where am I going wrong? I first thought maybe I have the data/labels mixed up for the clusters, but what I posted above looks correct I can't see an issue with it.

Why is the data that is the exact same unseen 10% data used in the first experiment yielding such strange results for the same unseen clustered data?  I mean it should be noted that NB is a stable classifier and shouldn't overfit easily and seeing as the training data is vast while the clusters to be classified are concurrent overfitting shouldn't happen?

**EDIT:**

As requested from comments I have included the cmat file for the first example of testing which gives an accuracy of **81.49%** and an err of **0.5040**:

[image]

Also requested was the a snippet of K, class and the related cmat in this example (cluster4) the accuracy is **3.03%**:

[image]

Seeing as there was a large number of classes (23 in total) I decided to reduce the classes as outlined in the [1999 KDD Cup](http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/training_attack_types) this is just applying a bit of domain knowledge as some of the attacks are more alike than others and come under one umbrella term.

I then trained the classifier with 444 thousand records while holding back 10% for testing purposes.

The accuracy was worse **73.39%** the error rate was also worse **0.4261**

[image]

The unseen data broken down into its classes:

```
DoS: 39149
Probe: 405
R2L: 121
U2R: 6
normal.: 9721
```

The class or classified labels (outcome of discriminant analysis):

```
DoS: 28135
Probe: 10776
R2L: 1102
U2R: 1140
normal.: 8249
```

The training data is made up of:

```
DoS: 352452
Probe: 3717
R2L: 1006
U2R: 49
normal.: 87395
```

I fear if I lower the training data to have a similar percentage of malicious activity, then the classifier won't have enough predictive power to distinguish between classes, however looking at some other literature I have noticed that some researchers remove U2R as there isn't enough data for successful classification.

Methods I have tried so far are one class classifiers where I train the classifier to only predict one class (not effective), classifying individual clusters (worse accuracy yet), reducing the class labels (2nd best) and keeping the full 23 class labels (best accuracy).

Comment: What are the **class sizes** in the whole data set and in each cluster?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what's in `training_data`, but it sounds like your training and testing data don't have any classes that overlap. if your training data does not include many instances of the class in the testing cluster, it will not be able to label them properly.

Comment: Whats in `training_data`... it says it in the code `training_data = Testdata;` test data is 90% (444 thousand records) I hold back 10% of this (44 thousand records) which is the `UnseenTestdata` this becomes the clustered data and each cluster is classified. So no Jeff your way off.

Comment: could you post a snippet of `K1`, `class1`, and `cmat1`?

Comment: My little useless advice: with classes so big (and I don't know their dimensions) you are going to have a hard time playing with the algorithms. To prove they work, generate a SIMPLE dataset, totally controlled by you, with few points, and experiment on them. Only when you are confident the algo work, try to apply it to the big, serious data. ;)

Comment: K1 is each cluster labels, class1 is obviously the labels it has classified of each cluster and cmat1 is the confusion matrix for each classified cluster... im not sure increasing the size of the question is a wise idea, people may already be put off with the size of it.

Comment: @Castilho Yes I have done this, I have also already proved they work :)

Comment: Could you also post the confusion matrix for the respective cases ? The main problem I find is with the number 0.5040 in err.....

Comment: Please note question is open to bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have correctly pointed out, at least one problem here is on these lines:

```
class1  = classify(cluster1, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear');
...
```

You are training the classifier using all the training_data, but evaluating it on only the sub-clusters.  For clustering the data to have any effect, you need to train a different classifier **within** each of the sub-clusters.  Sometimes this can be very difficult - e.g., there may be very few (or no!) examples in cluster C from class Y.  That's inherent to trying to do joint clustering and learning.

The general framework for your problem is as follows:

```
Training data:
   Cluster into C clusters
   Within each cluster, develop a classifier

Testing data:
   Assign observation into one of the C clusters (either "hard", or "soft")
   Run the correct classifier (corresponding to that cluster)
```

This

```
class1  = classify(cluster1, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear');
```

Does not do that.

Comment: "Within each cluster, develop a classifier" it is almost impossible to develop this with the darpa dataset so much so that if you try, your simply fitting the training data. For instance one cluster has normal and dos classes, if I create a classifier either 50:50 or 70:30 whatever is represented as the majority in the cluster and I train NB with this to predict the cluster classes, its accuracy falls way short in comparison to the accuracy of my first example.

Comment: Then the proposed approach is not relevant to the problem at hand.  That will happen.  There's not much that can be done about it, except try an alternate approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple example that shows exactly how this is supposed to work and what is wrong

```
%% Generate data and labels for each class
x11 = bsxfun(@plus,randn(100,2),[2 2]);
x10 = bsxfun(@plus,randn(100,2),[0 2]);

x21 = bsxfun(@plus,randn(100,2),[-2 -2]);
x20 = bsxfun(@plus,randn(100,2),[0 -2]);

%If you have the PRT (shameless plug), this looks nice:
%http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/linkexchange/links/2947-pattern-recognition-toolbox
% ds = prtDataSetClass(cat(1,x11,x21,x10,x20),prtUtilY(200,200));

x = cat(1,x11,x21,x10,x20);
y = cat(1,ones(200,1),zeros(200,1));

clusterIdx = kmeans(x,2); %make 2 clusters
xCluster1 = x(clusterIdx == 1,:);
yCluster1 = y(clusterIdx == 1);
xCluster2 = x(clusterIdx == 2,:);
yCluster2 = y(clusterIdx == 2);


%Performance is terrible:
yOut1  = classify(xCluster1, x, y, 'diaglinear');
yOut2  = classify(xCluster2, x, y, 'diaglinear');

pcCluster = length(find(cat(1,yOut1,yOut2) == cat(1,yCluster1,yCluster2)))/size(y,1)

%Performance is Good:
yOutCluster1  = classify(xCluster1, xCluster1, yCluster1, 'diaglinear');
yOutCluster2  = classify(xCluster2, xCluster2, yCluster2, 'diaglinear');

pcWithinCluster = length(find(cat(1,yOutCluster1,yOutCluster2) == cat(1,yCluster1,yCluster2)))/size(y,1)

%Performance is Bad (using all data):
yOutFull  = classify(x, x, y, 'diaglinear');
pcFull = length(find(yOutFull == y))/size(y,1)
```

Comment: You use the same training data as the testing data `classify(xCluster1, xCluster1` but in your other example you dont `classify(xCluster1, x` what happens if you try `classify(x, x` I bet you get the same results as yOutCluster1

Comment: Yes, I did not try cross-validating this.  You can.  You will see similar results to the ones I presented.  You can also try "yOutFull  = classify(x, x, y, 'diaglinear');"  and see that the performance is quite poor.  Not like the results from yOutCluster2.  This is easy to verify with the code provided

Comment: I edited the code snipped to include the above example.  It illustrates the point quite clearly.

Answer (score -1):

Look at your `cmat1` data of first example (with accuracy of 81.49%), the main reason that you get high accuracy is that your classifier get large amount of `class 1` and `class 4` correct. almost all the other classes perform badly(getting zero correct predictions). And this is consistent with your last example(using k-means first), where for cluster7 you get acc7 of 56.9698.

**EDIT**:
It seems that in `cmat1`, we do not have testing data for more that half of the classes(looking at the all-zero lines). So you can only know the general performance for classes like `1` and `4` is good, and will get similar performance if you do clustering first. But for other classes, this is no evidence that it works ok.

Comment: I already know this, you havent mentioned anything knew and infact your answer is wrong in regards to the clustered data. K-means successfully clusters DoS and Normal however classifying these does not produce the same results as in the first example or anywhere near the accuracy, of which it was good at predicting. Also please read the bounty description in regards to an answer.

Comment: Also what do you mean by `we do not have testing data for more that half of the classes(looking at the all-zero lines)`

Comment: I may misunderstood your problem. I am pointing out that your NB classifier does not perform that well. The accuracy(81.49%) comes from the total testing instance(49402) divided by the summation of all diagonal terms of confusion matrix(2802+9+1669+10139+...=40259). As you can see, two classes(1 and 4) contribute to the most of the accuracy, and large amount of classes has no correct prediction at all. This problem is due to the imbalance of dataset, since the instances for these two classes are too many. And there is no surprise that later you get many 0% accuracy for individual clusters.

Comment: Dataset balance is important for classifiers such as Naive Bayes, and you cannot simply use NB if your dataset is unbalanced. Search on Google and you may find many papers dealing with this problem.

Answer (score -1):

After you cluster your data, are you traning a classifier for each cluster? If you are not doing this, then this may be your problem.

Try doing this. First, cluster your data and keep the centroids. Then, using the training data, train a classifier per clusters. For the classification phase, find the nearest centroid of the object you want to classify and use the corresponding classifier.

A single classifier is not a good idea because it learns patterns of the whole dataset. However, what you want when you cluster is to learn the local patterns that describes each cluster.

Comment: That doesnt make sense. When you train a classifier in this instance naive bayes you train it on as many samples as you can or on a balanced dataset that describes the classes, when testing the accuracy in my circumstance you test it on the unseen clustered testdata i.e each cluster.

Comment: Also note each cluster has its own training and classification but each cluster is trained on the same training data. So im not sure if you read the question?

Comment: In your question you say "...run each individual cluster through a classification algorithm." How do you train this classifier? That is, which instances do you use to train it. Is it the whole dataset or only instances that belong to the cluster?

Comment: As explained in the question, I break the dataset into two parts. 90% of the dataset is used for training, the remaining 10% is used for testing. The testing part is first clustered and each cluster is classifyed using the training data.

Answer (score -1):

Consider this function call:

```
classify(cluster1, training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear');
```

`training_data` is a sample of the whole feature space. What that means? The classification model that you are training will try to maximize the classification accuracy for the whole feature space. That means that if you show test samples that have the same behavior as your training data, you will get classification results.

The point is that you are not showing test samples that have the same behavior as your training data. In fact cluster1 is a sample of only a partition of your feature space. More specifically, the instances in cluster1 corresponds to samples of your feature space that are closer to the centroid of cluster1 than the remaining centroids and this may be degrading your classifier performance.

So I suggest you the following:

1. Cluster your training set and keep the centroids
2. Using the training data, train a classifier per cluster. That is, use only instances that belong to that cluster to train the classifier.
3. For the classification phase, find the nearest centroid of the object you want to classify and use the corresponding classifier.

Comment: So if I cluster the training data and keep the average mean of lets say cluster 1 which is "normal" classes, I then use this as the training data for NB, I then cluster my unseen data and I find that either none of the clusters have the same average mean or they do but when I try to classify based on the training examples I find that NB has only one class to train on and has hugely overfit the data and is bias to only one class (normal in this example)?

Comment: Note that you should not cluster the test data.

Comment: Well I had thought that if I cluster the entire dataset then take out 10% of each cluster for training the classifier on for each of those matching clusters, this would be the only way it would work with your proposed method. Because note that if I cluster both training and testing seperately and take only the centroids of training data and the centroids of testing data, then they do not match. The numbers are completely different.